# Box-sizing: border box; percentage width but pixel padding

Tags: html, css, flexbox, border-box

I've been creating a grid, which uses `padding` for gutters. There's times where It's necessary to have no gutters (full `width` image) so I simply created a class which removed the `padding`.

The problem is, when using a `50%` `width`, even though it's using `border-box`, is not truly `50%`.

a reduced test case:

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sce7j3u8/)

**Code**

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.row {
  zoom: 1;
  &: before, &: after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
  }
  &:after {
    clear: both;
  }
}
.half {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
}
.no-pad {
  padding: 0;
}
.column {
  float: left;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
.eq-height-container {
  display: flex;
}
.eq-height-column {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="row eq-height-container">
  <div class="column half eq-height-column" style="background-color: red;">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa necessitatibus qui ea, quasi pariatur sed esse beatae porro in temporibus ipsum delectus, quisquam. Saepe sapiente, facere repellat tenetur quae aut.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column half no-pad eq-height-column">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" alt="">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row eq-height-container">
  <div class="column half no-pad eq-height-column">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="column half eq-height-column" style="background-color: red;">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa necessitatibus qui ea, quasi pariatur sed esse beatae porro in temporibus ipsum delectus, quisquam. Saepe sapiente, facere repellat tenetur quae aut.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there a simple way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can set `img` to `width:100%` and remove `flex:1` and `float:left` as well if you want to keep `display:flex` for equal height

```css
body {
  margin: 0
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.row::before,
.row::after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.row::after {
  clear: both;
}
.half {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  background: red
}
.no-pad {
  padding: 0;
}
 img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
.eq-height-container {
  display: flex;
}
.eq-height-column {
  /* flex: 1;*/
}
```

```html
<div class="row eq-height-container">
  <div class="column half eq-height-column">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa necessitatibus qui ea, quasi pariatur sed esse beatae porro in temporibus ipsum delectus, quisquam. Saepe sapiente, facere repellat tenetur quae aut.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column half no-pad eq-height-column">
    <img src="//lorempixel.com/400/200" alt="">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row eq-height-container">
  <div class="column half no-pad eq-height-column">
    <img src="//lorempixel.com/400/200" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="column half eq-height-column">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa necessitatibus qui ea, quasi pariatur sed esse beatae porro in temporibus ipsum delectus, quisquam. Saepe sapiente, facere repellat tenetur quae aut.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're mixing in `flex`. If you remove `.eq-height-column` you'll see that the two columns become the same width.

Comment: Ah, - interesting. It would be good to keep the flex for the equal height goodness it gives. Is there any way around this?

Comment: Not too familiar with `flexbox` but why not build your columns with it also since you're already using it? I'm assuming the [support levels](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox) of `flexbox` meets your requirements?

Comment: It's used for a very small portion of the site (1 page), so opted to use flexbox out of ease (wouldn't be the end of the world for unsupported browsers to have uneven columns), but I would like the keep my main grid non-flex.